# jQuery replaceWith() callback function to update things

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, replacewith

I am using jQuery replaceWith() method to replace some content from the html. Its working fine. But I want to change the data attribute value once replaceWith() has been done.

So basically I am getting this from my ajax response

```
UpdatedItem = '<li data-cart-key="XXX" data-item-name="Test" data-item-price="$111.00" data-item-key="XXX"><span class="cart-action-wrap"><a class="edit-cart-item" data-cart-item="XXX" data-cart-key="XXX" data-cart-action="edit">Edit</a><a class="remove-cart-item" data-cart-item="XXX" data-cart-key="XXX" data-cart-action="remove">Remove</a></span></li>';
```

Now I am using replaceWith() here like this

```
$( 'ul.custom-contents' ).find( 'li.updated' ).replaceWith( UpdatedItem );
```

Here I wanted to use methods like update data attribute value, remove class, add class after replaceWith() has been done.

So can someone tell me is there any way available to do this? Any help and suggestions would be really appreciable. Thanks

Comment: "_change the data attribute value_" you want to change data of which element?

Comment: @Nick sorry for that. I have accepted the answer, Thanks for that.

Comment: @Nick actually the solution what I have accepted  worked fine without any issues and I forgot to accept that. But anyways I have accepted the answer.

Comment: Do any of the below answers solve your issue? Please mark one as the correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a jQuery object inside `replaceWith`, do the operations and return it. Use `.find()` for nested elements:

```
$( 'ul.custom-contents' ).find( 'li.updated' ).replaceWith( fucntion(){
   let obj = $(UpdatedItem)   
   obj.addClass("..")
   obj.data("cart-key", "..")
   obj.data("item-name", "..")
   obj.removeClass("..")

   //Find <a> with class "edit-cart-item"
   obj.find("a.edit-cart-item").addClass(...)
   obj.find("a.edit-cart-item").data("item-name", "..")
   return obj;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but if there is nested html then its not working with find with class name.

Comment: There's no mention of a nested element anywhere in the question. Please post all the information.

Comment: @NewUser atleast explain in your post what is not working? Like what you tried but it didn't give the result how you expected? Just saying not working is so trivial in the context.

Comment: @NewUser Don't forget to be generous with upvotes as well :)

Answer (score 1):

you can solve like this.

```js
UpdatedItem =
  '<li data-cart-key="" data-item-name="Test" data-item-price="$111.00" data-item-key="XXX">updated</li>';
divElement = document.createElement("div");
divElement.innerHTML = UpdatedItem;
element = divElement.firstElementChild;
$("ul.custom-contents").find("li.updated").replaceWith(element);

element.setAttribute("data-item-name", "myValue");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

</head>

<body>


  <ul class="custom-contents">
    <li class="updated">old</li>
    <li class="">old</li>
    <li class="">old</li>
  </ul>


  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @NewUser if this is a correct answer, you can mark this answer as correct for future readings.